# How to test functions in a private directory?

Tags: unit-testing, matlab, xunit

I'm using [MATLAB xUnit](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework) to test some code.  I'd like to be able to directly call some functions that are contained in a `private` directory.

Here's a simple replicable setup:
Create yourself a project directory with two folders `code` and `test`.  In `code`, create a subdirectory named `private` so you directory tree looks like

```
project_root
  code
    private
  test
```

In the `code` directory place a function

```
function y = main()
y = sub();
end
```

In the `private` dir place a function

```
function y = sub()
y = 123;
end
```

In the `test` dir place a function

```
function testsub()
assertElementsAlmostEqual(sub(), 123);
end
```

Now navigate to the test dir and call `runtests`.  You should see an error saying that `sub` is undefined.

`private` directories aren't allowed on the matlab path so that isn't an option. I could possibly put a function in the `code` dir that retrieves handles to all the private functions but this seems hacky.

What is the best way to get access to test the private functions?

EDIT:

The idea of navigating to the private directory has a problem.  In theory I could call, e.g.,

```
cd(privateDirectory);
suite = TestSuite.fromName(testDirectory);
suite.run
```

Unfortunately the testing framework navigates to the directory containing the tests as soon as you call `run`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to navigate to the private directory from *within* `testsub`, get a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html) to the private function you want using [STR2FUNC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html), then navigate back to do the testing using that function handle. You could even put these steps in a separate helper function for your unit testing, like so:

```
function privateFcn = get_private_fcn(privateDir,fcnName)
  oldDir = cd(privateDir);         %# Change to the private directory
  privateFcn = str2func(fcnName);  %# Get a function handle
  cd(oldDir);                      %# Change back to the original directory
end
```

And you would use this function in `testsub` as follows:

```
function testsub()
  privateDir = '...\project_root\code\private';    %# The path to the private
                                                   %#   directory
  privateFcn = get_private_fcn(privateDir,'sub');  %# Call get_private_fcn
  assertElementsAlmostEqual(privateFcn(), 123);    %# Apply your test
end
```

This works, although the MATLAB Editor gives me an [M-Lint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mlint.html) warning for using the function [CD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cd.html): "MCC use of the CD function is problematic." I think it's safe for you to ignore this warning since 1) the function `get_private_fcn` changes the current directory, then immediately changes it back after getting the function handle and 2) you're not [dealing with a deployed application](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/).

Answer (score 3):

While you cannot put a private directory on your search path, you CAN cd to the private directory itself.

Once there, MATLAB will see the functions, and it can use them. This is how I do that testing myself on private functions.

Comment: Inspired, but ultimately thwarted in this case.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The point of private directories is to have functions that have very limited visibility, i.e. only to the functions in `code`. Thus, there is no official way (at least that I know of) to make them visible.

The function that would retrieve the handles to whatever is in `code/private` seems to me the cleanest way to go about it.

The alternative would be to place `testsub` inside `code`. This has the advantage that the test functions are always together with the code they're supposed to test, but you may feel this "pollutes" your code directory.

Comment: Yeah, I much prefer to keep test code separate from "real" code.